# Что означают файлы вида 's0:c129,c432' в корневом разделе?

Tags: linux, файловая-система, raid

В корневом разделе ОС появляются файлы вида 's0:c129,c432'
Файлы пустые, ни какими процессами не задействованы.

Что они означают? Это говорит о проблемах с файловой системой?

Comment: а что в файлах? lsof показывает, что их кто-то использует?

Comment: Файлы пустые, никто их не использует, это не могут быть метки поврежденных секторов файловой системы?